# Salesforce HTML Status Not Working with Visualforce Page and Visualforce Component

Tags: apex, visualforce, scheduled-apex, html

I used a visualforce page with this syntax:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0">
```

that calls a visualforce component with html syntax (here's sample):

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="Fo_EmailSummaryController">
```

Visualforce Template used

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false"     standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0">
    <c:Fo_EmailSummary email="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.email}" browser="true"/>
```

I scheduled an Apex Batch and fired it off to 2,000 emails. They all went through, but was wondering if my layout is out dated or if something I did wrong didn't work with the HTML Email Status functionality? None of the emails have any indication of them being opened not even sent when using the reports

Comment: Did you set an HTML body? Without that, it won't track it.

Comment: Ah maybe I need to add them to my visualforce template?                                                              <apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0">
 <c:Fo_EmailSummary email="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.email}" browser="true"/>
</apex:page>

Comment: This is how the vf template was setup. Did I miss something that should’ve been added?